# how can i make a model from several smaller objects

Tags: modeling, rigging, particles

I am not too advanced into blender but i was wondering how you could make a model like a person made of several smaller objects (like korg from thor: ragnarok but a lot less detailed)

Answer (score 1):

You can join meshes by selecting two meshes and hit CTRL-J. After that go edit mode and tidy up the resulting mesh by removing overlaps and by adding connections.